# The interception Lp with Lq is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

Please, help me with this question:

Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and $1\leq q \leq\infty$, with $\Omega$ open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that is closed in $L^p(\Omega)$ the set

$\{f\in L^p(\Omega)\cap L^q(\Omega); \|f\|_{q}\leq 1\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is immediate form Fatou's Lemma. Let $\{f_n\}$ be as sequence in this set converging in $L^{p}$ norm to $f$. Then there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ which converges almost everywhere to $f$.   $\int |f^{q}| =\int \lim \inf |f_{n_k}|^{q}\leq \lim \inf \int |f_{n_k}|^{q}\leq 1$.